# Dnsmasq - Do not log certain queries/websites?

Tags: linux, systemd-journald, dnsmasq

I have dnsmasq logging to my systemd-journal on a machine hosting an apache server. The server is quite busy, causing around 600.000 log lines to accumulate within 4-5 hours. Out of these logs, 94% are from dnsmasq. And of the dnsmasq logs, 99% are the same two lines: 127.0.0.1 asks for website_A. website_A is cached.

These lines are useless to me, I need basically everything BUT these tw from dnsmasq. I would like to exclude this website/query from dnsmasq logging. AFAIK it is not possible? Does someone have an idea to solve this?

I guess I could make a cronjob and using sed remove these two exact lines. I would need to make dnsmasq put its logs outside of systemd because the journal files are binary and I dont know how to read/manipulate them. Probably better not to anyways.

Anyone have a better idea?